# How to save an MS Word using diferent URL C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

---

I am working into MS Word with C#. I have a MS Word document and I have a library of "folders" from Sharepoint, the "Folder" have other folders. Now I have a constant url, it's

```
@"http: // ... / Folders"
```

The rest depends of user selection. I thought in the SaveAs method, but it will not let me put a url. then i thought if i could open de SaveAs form with the specific url. But I cant find the form to do it.

Any idea?

Comment: What version of MS Word are you using?

Comment: iam using MS word 2013

Comment: May be some code sharing will help us to help you? How are you creating/opening MS Word document? How are you trying to save it?

Comment: public  void RdSalvar()
        {
            object filename = @"D:\Nueva carpeta\"+_Titulo+".docx";
        
                ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref filename, ref missing, ref missing,   ...);            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Error" + exception.Message);
            }
        }

Comment: It is the method, but I want the user can choose the url